# Why @Qualifier not work

Tags: spring-boot

I used spring boot + jdbctemplate and I have to use multi datasource, e.g.

```java
@Configuration
public class MultiDBConfig {

    @Bean(name = "fooDb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "foo.datasource")
    public DataSource fooDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "fooJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate fooJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("fooDb") DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

    @Bean(name = "barDb")
    @ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "bar.datasource")
    public DataSource barDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "barJdbcTemplate")
    public JdbcTemplate barJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("barDb") DataSource ds) {
        return new JdbcTemplate(ds);
    }

}
```

when start my application, it failed and have below error info

```
Parameter 0 of method fooJdbcTemplate in com.example.multidatasourcedemo.MultiDBConfig required a single bean, but 3 were found:
    - fooDb: defined by method 'fooDataSource' in class path resource [com/example/multidatasourcedemo/MultiDBConfig.class]
    - barDb: defined by method 'barDataSource' in class path resource [com/example/multidatasourcedemo/MultiDBConfig.class]
    - testDb: defined by method 'testDataSource' in class path resource [com/example/multidatasourcedemo/MultiDBConfig.class]


Action:

Consider marking one of the beans as @Primary, updating the consumer to accept multiple beans, or using @Qualifier to identify the bean that should be consumed
```

But I obviously have used `@Qualifier` to identify the bean , e.g.

```java
@Bean(name = "fooJdbcTemplate")
public JdbcTemplate fooJdbcTemplate(@Qualifier("fooDb") DataSource ds)
```

Why doesn't `@Qualifier` work here?

Comment: Can you mark three *JdbcTemplate classes with `@Primary` annotation and try? This way we tell Spring to give preference when many candidates are qualified to autowire.

Comment: By the looks of your config, this should work. What boot version are you using, and can you share a [sscce](http://sscce.org) to do some more debugging? On a separate note, you can also [call the method that generates your bean](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html) (scroll to `@Bean Methods in @Configuration Classes`) inside the config class, eg: `return new JdbcTemplate(fooDataSource());`

Comment: @Morfic I'm used the latest 1.5.4. I have committed  this small demo to github--https://github.com/zhugw/multi-datasource-demo

Comment: Your app starts just fine on my PC. I don't have a DB running locally so accessing `http://localhost:8080/?name=foo` after adding `@RequestParam(value = "name")` in your controller, throws an exception which is expected , but it starts normally without any issues. What am I missing?

Comment: @Morfic because I have added a @Primary on `fooDataSource()`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I missed that, I somehow was expecting it to fail from the start so I don't think I even looked for `@Primary`. Nonetheless, I've done a small investigation and summarised my findings in an answer below. Cheers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So I've done some debugging and found something which might explain what's happening. At this point I'm not sure if it's a bug (could be [this one](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/9528)), but I have not been able to find any other documentation to clarify this either.

For reference this is spring-boot 1.5.4.

---

I started from the log, you can find below an excerpt, more specifically the line regarding `DataSourceInitializer.init` (below with `==>` at the beginning):

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'javax.sql.DataSource' available: expected single matching bean but found 3: fooDb,barDb,testDb
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveNamedBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1041) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:345) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBean(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:340) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1090) ~[spring-context-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
==> at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer.init(DataSourceInitializer.java:77) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar:1.5.4.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_45]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE.jar:4.3.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:311) ~[spring-beans-4.3.9.RELEASE
    ...
```

What happens is, when initialising the data sources, spring-boot tries to initialise the DB as well, feature which is enabled by default according to [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-database-initialization.html#howto-initialize-a-database-using-spring-jdbc):

> Spring JDBC has a `DataSource` initializer feature. Spring Boot enables it by default and loads SQL from the standard locations `schema.sql` and `data.sql` (in the root of the classpath).

This takes place in the `@PostConstruct` section of `org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jdbc.DataSourceInitializer`:

```java
@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    if (!this.properties.isInitialize()) {
        logger.debug("Initialization disabled (not running DDL scripts)");
        return;
    }
    if (this.applicationContext.getBeanNamesForType(DataSource.class, false, false).length > 0) {
        ==> this.dataSource = this.applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);
    }
    if (this.dataSource == null) {
        logger.debug("No DataSource found so not initializing");
        return;
    }
    runSchemaScripts();
}
```

As you can see, it tries to get the `DataSource` to execute the DB initialisation using the class `this.dataSource = this.applicationContext.getBean(DataSource.class);` and since there are 3 instances and no primary, it fails as per the [expected behaviour of `getBean(class)`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/BeanFactory.html#getBean-java.lang.Class-)

> <T> T **getBean**(Class<T> requiredType) throws BeansException
>   
> Return the bean instance that uniquely matches the given object type, if any.
>   
> This method goes into ListableBeanFactory by-type lookup territory but may also be translated into a conventional by-name lookup based on the name of the given type. For more extensive retrieval operations across sets of beans, use ListableBeanFactory and/or BeanFactoryUtils.
>
> Parameters:
>   
> requiredType - type the bean must match; can be an interface or superclass. null is disallowed.
>
> Returns:
>   
> an instance of the single bean matching the required type
>
> **Throws**:
>   
> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException - if no bean of the given type was found
>   
> **==> NoUniqueBeanDefinitionException** - if more than one bean of the given type was found
>   
> BeansException - if the bean could not be created

---

So, bottom line, this happens before even trying to autowire your `@Qualifier("fooDb")` bean in the method, and I believe you have at lease these 2 choices, and in both cases your `@Qualifier` will be taken into account at the time when your `JdbcTemplate` is created:

- if you need to execute some scripts to initialise your DB, then use `@Primary` to indicate which `DataSource` could be used for the task
- otherwise, you can disable this implicit feature by adding `spring.datasource.initialize=false` in your `application.properties` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) a list of common properties that can be configured)

Comment: Thanks!  So actually this error has nothing to do with my code, because 
 it's something elsewhere has not specify @Qualify when get a DataSource

Comment: @zhuguowei indeed, it doesn't have to do with your code, but it's not that simple to point a finger at the culprit. It's related to the spring-boot series of tools that make our development easier, in this case the DB initialisation which requires a `DataSource` to do it but it's not tied to your bean and it can't know about your qualifiers. It would require someone with Spring source-code knowledge to say whether this can be classified as a bug, or how it can be improved. It's also possible that you could define your own `DataSourceInitializer` but I did not dig that deep...

Comment: yeah, but at least the error message is not very clear and could cause mislead, in addition I have to set `debug=true` explicitly could see the stack trace and know actually it's from `DataSourceInitializer.init`

Comment: @zhuguowei true, perhaps you could add a comment on that issue I linked at the start of the answer and see what they have to say, whether it can be taken into consideration inside that issue, or if a new one is required. You can also link this stack-overflow question in the comment for more information, and perhaps they can add other suggestions here as well.

Comment: Excellent research.  Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by a few different things. In my case, I had the following situation:

- Two Datasource beans being configured in two Java classes, but both given specific Bean IDs
- One place a Datasource was being injected, but correctly annotated with a Qualifier
- A SpringBootApplication that was correctly excluding DataSourceAutoConfiguration

However, the bug turned out to be: a second class had been annotated as a SpringBootApplication and that was starting up...lost among the logs.
So, if everything else looks correct: check if some other, unexpected, SpringBootApplication is starting up.